# Scroll to div on entering website

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I'm using this code to scroll to specific areas of my website.
What function should I add to this code to scroll to specific div when entering website?

```
$(window).load(function(){
function goToByScroll(id){
          // Remove "link" from the ID
        id = id.replace("link", "");
          // Scroll
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollLeft: $("#"+id).offset().left},
            'slow');
    }

    $("#index > a").click(function(e) { 
          // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
        e.preventDefault(); 
          // Call the scroll function
        goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));           
    });
});
```

Comment: You could simply try calling it in $(document).ready()

Comment: what is your page url structure? can you post them as well?

Comment: @Sebastian Smith Please consider green-checking answer if answer served your purpose.More details here on how to do so  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  goToByScroll('DivID');
});
```

see this examlple http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/1141/

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Put it inside windows.load(function(){//here}) block

```
goToByScroll('yourDivId');
```

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it doesn't seem to work. Maybe you could write a full code? My javascript knowledge is very poor..